# How to get the user's choice properly when the choice is too complex to use UIAlertView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates, nsobject

I have been struggling with this problem for a while now, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the situation: My application has a `UIViewController` subclass called `InitialViewController`. This view controller has a UIButton, and when that button is pressed it creates a `NSObject` subclass called `MyEngine`. Something like this:

```
@interface InitialViewController : UIViewController <MyEngineDelegate>
...
@end

@implementation InitialViewController
...
-(IBAction)pressedButton:(id)sender {
    MyEngine *engine = [[MyEngine alloc] init];
    [engine start];
}
```

Inside `start`, I present a ViewController (`ConflictViewController`) modally to get the user's choice:

```
@interface MyEngine : NSObject <ConflictViewControllerDelegate>
...
-(void) start;
@end

@implementation MyEngine
...
-(void) start {
        ConflictViewcontroller *cvc = [[ConflictViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ConflictViewController" bundle:nil];
        cvc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
        cvc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        cvc.delegate = self;
        UIWindow *window = [(MyAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
        [[window rootViewController] presentModalViewController:cvc animated:YES];
}
@end
```

`ConflictViewController` is really simple. It just waits for the user to decide, and when the user press the button, it send the message to the `delegate`, and dismiss itself.

```
-(IBAction)didSelectConflict:(id)sender {
    UISegmentedControl *seg = (UISegmentedControl*) sender;
    [self.delegate didResolveConflictChoice:seg.selectedSegmentIndex];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I've checked every connection, all the delegates are working properly.
What is going wrong is:
When MyEngine receives the user's choice in it's implementation of `didSelectConflict:` it cannot continue properly because all of it's properties have gone `null`.

When the `MyEngine` presents the `ConflictViewController`, the program continues the execution and when `start` finishes, it goes back to `pressedButton:` and when this method is closed, the `MyEngine` object gets released.

What i want to know is if there is way around this ? Has anyone done something like this in another way ? 
The question here is: How to get the user's choice properly when the choice is too complex to use `UIAlertView`.

Sorry for the long question, I simplified it as much as I could. Thanks for your time, any links, comments, or any kind of help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you initializing `MyEngine *engine` in the IBAction, if you wish to use a MyEngine object why don't you make a global declaration in your `InitialViewController` and just call `[engine start]` in the IBaction. Then when the delegate method returns the selected index you can apply that to a global int in your initial view controller and continue on your way. Hope that makes sense

Comment: Indeed. That does make sense hahaha. Still, i wish I knew a better way to handle this kind of situation

Answer (score 0):

Make your method start as

```
-(void) startWithDelegate:(id)del {
        ConflictViewcontroller *cvc = [[ConflictViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ConflictViewController" bundle:nil];
        cvc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
        cvc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        cvc.delegate = del;
        UIWindow *window = [(MyAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
        [[window rootViewController] presentModalViewController:cvc animated:YES];
}
```

and

```
-(IBAction)pressedButton:(id)sender {
    MyEngine *engine = [[MyEngine alloc] init];
    [engine startWithDelegate:self];
}
```

implement `didResolveConflictChoice:` in `InitialViewController` and get the delegate call there.
**OR** you can use [UIActionSheet](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/04/14/iphone-uiactionsheet-example/) if suitable.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that I need `MyEngine`'s properties to work with `didResolveConflictChoice:`. I will take a look at UIActionSheet. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Unfortunately `UIActionSheet` is just a set of buttons, exactly like `UIAlertView`

Comment: Give a try on above method. other wise you can put table view in alert view as in this tutorial http://starterstep.wordpress.com/2009/03/24/custom-uialertview-with-uitableview/